# How to encode string in JSTL or JSP

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, jstl, encode

How to encode string in JSTL or JSP?

${itemTitle} contains quotes("), so IE is unable to parse and total page is broken.

Comment: The term should be called escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<c:out>`:

```
<c:out value="${itemTitle}"/>
```

This will replace `"` with `&quot;`.

Comment: Would you mind [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) please, as well as any answers to previous questions that solved your problems?